# Cypress check is element has scroll bar visible

Tags: cypress

I have list that should have 10 elements, if the list contains 11 elements i need to show scroll, the container is fixed size.
Everything is ok but how i can check that scroll is exist?

```
cy.get('[data-testid=list-box]')
```

Comment: Perhaps you can test if element 11 is visible?

Comment: or compare the list scrollHeight to clientHeight.

Comment: @HiramK.Hackenbacker What i actually did, i scrolled to bottom and checked that 11 element is became visible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing this by measuring the height and scrollHeight with jQuery.

```js
  it("should force scroll within a large body", () => {
    cy.get(".lorem-ipsum-header").click();
    cy.get(".section-body")
      .should("have.length", 1)
      .eq(0)
      .should("contain.text", "Lorem ipsum")
      .then(($body) => {
        cy.wrap($body).invoke("outerHeight").should("eq", 583);
        cy.wrap($body).invoke("prop", "scrollHeight").should("eq", 1892);
      });
  });
```

Comment: If you are only checking one item, there is no need to use .then and rewrap $body.
.invoke('prop', 'scrollHeight') can be used directly

Answer (score 0):

You could get the count of elements and if the length of the list is `less than or equal to 10` do some action, else check for the `visibility` of `scrollbar`. Please try below test and let me know

```
it('Check the length of the list', () => {
        cy.get('[data-testid=list-box]')
            .then(list => {
            const listCount = Cypress.$(list).length;
            if(listCount <= 10){
             // do some action if the list count is less than 10..
            }else{
              cy.get('#scrollbar_Id').should('be.visible');
            }

        });
    })
```

Comment: what is #scrollbar_Id ?

Comment: I just give that as an example for you, using inspect you should get the real `class` or `id` or selector of the `scroll bar` displaying .

Comment: Maybe i miss something but scroll bar does not have any id or class.. 
Only the element has some selector, but i already know that element is visible i need to know if scroll present on this element.

Comment: @Alexander Gorelik, do you mean a scrollbar should be visible for the browserwindow or a specific element (I guess you have a drop down selector of some sort?) ?. It can be possible that the developers added a property to the element `list-box` that it is has a scrollbar. If it is not you can ask them to add it. If you are looking for the browserwindows scrollbar, you can't confirm that, to my best knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm getting the last element. Then used cypress scrollIntoView() to scroll to that last element. And using should() to see it's visible or not.

```
cy.get('Selector')
  .last()
  .within(($element) => {
    if (!$element.is(':visible')) {
      cy.wrap($element).scrollIntoView();
    }})
  .should('be.visible');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your parent container has a style of `overflow-y: auto`, you can use:

```js
cy.get('[data-testid=list-box]').parent()
  .then($scrollBox => 
        expect($scrollBox[0].clientHeight)
               .to.be.lessThan($scrollBox[0].scrollHeight));
```

as these two properties would be `equal` if there is no scrollbar visible, but `scrollHeight` would be larger than `clientHeight` if the scrollbar is shown.

Answer (score -1):

> Basically, we get the element from the jquery wrapper and then test if it is scrollable by comparing scrollWidth and actualWidth

```
export enum ScrollType {
    scrollable='scrollable',
    nonScrollable='non-scrollable',
}
export const isXScrollable = (element: HTMLElement) => {
    return element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth
};
export const isYScrollable = (element: HTMLElement) => {
    return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight;
}
export const isScrollable = (element: HTMLElement) => {
    return isXScrollable(element) || isYScrollable(element)
}

describe('Test',() => {
it('check that max of only 4 lines to be shown in the text area, and then it should add the scroll', () => {
    mount(<Textarea defaultValue="Line 1" id="textbox-abc2" ></Textarea>);
    const textbox = cy.get('#textbox-abc2');
    textbox.type('{enter}Line 2{enter}Line 3{enter}Line 4');
    textbox.then(a => {
      const scrollable = isYScrollable(a[0]) ? ScrollType.scrollable: ScrollType.nonScrollable
      expect(scrollable).to.eq(ScrollType.nonScrollable);
    })
    textbox.type('{enter}Line 5');
    textbox.then(a => {
      const scrollable = isYScrollable(a[0]) ? ScrollType.scrollable: ScrollType.nonScrollable
      expect(scrollable).to.eq(ScrollType.scrollable);
    })
  })
})
```